# Adding a DIV box below the modal image for description

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using a grid gallery for my web based application. The gallery doesn't have a description box for the image and I don't figure how to manually add one.

If I try to add a div inside the `<div class="content"></div>` which holds my image, the image fails to load in full view when click. I tried multiple methods, even went through some tricks and tutorials on the web but nothing seemed to work. Even if the div inside the content class loads, it takes the width of the entire full screen (more than the width of the image).

All the images have a separate width and height so I can't fix the width too. Here is a sample of what I want to achieve and my current codes in codepen snippet.

Here is the Sample: https://prnt.sc/plhqcr

Code Pen Snippet: https://codepen.io/zoomkraft/pen/KKKNVXN

This description box is what I want in FULL VIEW of the image (single image when clicked for full view) and not on the gallery view. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Could you show us what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think it is the 10th time I see this codePan Snippet and the question to add a description box. So I figuered out and get the following step-by-step solution:

**Changes in HTML**

Add a Div with the class: .desc as a child to every Div with the class od .gallery-item. The New Div .desc holds the Description.

```
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,care" alt="">
    <div class="desc">This is my Image Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Changes in CSS**

Set the img display type in the class ".full .content" (.full .content img {) to block. Also set the mas-height to 80%.

```
.full .content img {
  left: 50%;
  display:block;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation: zoomin 1s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Now add the classes for .content .desc and .full .content. desc

```
.content .desc {
  display:none;
  height:20%;
}
.full .content .desc {
  display:block;
  height:20%;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
```

**Changes to JS**

Code first ...

```
var gallery = document.querySelector("#gallery");
var getVal = function(elem, style) {
  return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(style));
};
var getHeight = function(item) {
  return item.querySelector(".content").getBoundingClientRect().height;
};
var resizeAll = function() {
  var altura = getVal(gallery, "grid-auto-rows");
  var gap = getVal(gallery, "grid-row-gap");
  gallery.querySelectorAll(".gallery-item").forEach(function(item) {
    var el = item;
    el.style.gridRowEnd =
      "span " + Math.ceil((getHeight(item) + gap) / (altura + gap));
  });

  gallery.querySelectorAll(".full").forEach(function(item) {
var imgwidth = item.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].clientWidth;
    var desc = item.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0];
    desc.style.width=imgwidth+"px";
 });
};
gallery.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(item) {
  item.classList.add("byebye");
  if (item.complete) {
    console.log(item.src);
  } else {
    item.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var altura = getVal(gallery, "grid-auto-rows");
      var gap = getVal(gallery, "grid-row-gap");
      var gitem = item.parentElement.parentElement;
      gitem.style.gridRowEnd =
        "span " + Math.ceil((getHeight(gitem) + gap) / (altura + gap));
      item.classList.remove("byebye");
    });
  }
});
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAll);
gallery.querySelectorAll(".gallery-item").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if ((item.classList.contains("full") && ['IMG', 'A'].includes(event.target.tagName)) || (item.classList.contains("full") && ['desc'].includes(event.target.className))) {
      return;
    }
    item.classList.toggle("full");
    var imgwidth = item.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].clientWidth;
    var desc = item.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0];
    desc.style.width=imgwidth+"px";
  });
});
```

To the resizeAll function we added a small snippet to resize the .desc class if screen is resizing by the image width.
In the .gallery-item click function we add a small code to size the div after toggle.

Thats all and for me at works fine and meets your requirements.

Here you will find the updated Code Pen: https://codepen.io/MatWer/pen/XWWNGoK (With only the first Item has the desc .class)

Comment: Thank you. It works. I wish it was answered first time so I wouldn't have to through the trouble of asking it multiple times. I am sorry for that. But, when I click on description box, the image closes. Why? I don't get it. It should close only when clicked outside the area somewhere in the dark are as its working right now. Why is it happening? Any fix in the JS ?

Comment: I changed the code in JS ... Add the line if ((item.classList.contains("full") && ['IMG', 'A'].includes(event.target.tagName)) there is now an additional check for clicks on class .desc :-) ... CodePen is also updates. If the answer statisfied. Pls mark question as solved

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciated. :D